# why dislay :inline not working (not showing two div parallel)

Tags: css, ionic-framework

could you please tell me why **display:inline** not work .I am trying to show two div parallel or aside (as show in image).
[image]

Actually my div coming below the div .I need to show divs adjacently 
here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/Ny3wPlMG5F1ZbBtachdN?p=preview

```
#slideTest{
      margin-top:1em;
      border:1px solid pink;
      width:200px;
      height:100px;

    }
    .slider-pager{
      border:1px solid red;

    }

    #contendText{
      border:1px solid brown;
    }
    #rightContainer{
            display:inline;

    }
```

Comment: Check it out [http://plnkr.co/edit/muWRIcUxNJH0eU0ksg7I](http://plnkr.co/edit/muWRIcUxNJH0eU0ksg7I)

Answer (score 0):

the two item you want set inline should both be 'display: inline' or 'display: inline-block', their width add together should not be larger than parent container width.

so for the div and the image element or image container, you may need set the width.

Comment: inline-block works, check it: http://plnkr.co/edit/3ajV1AYhGzTHoQiTZcsd?p=preview